# Can a valid Ogg/Opus stream contain repeated Opus headers?

Tags: streaming, opus

The definition of an Ogg/Opus stream requires two headers at the beginning of the stream. These headers are required by decoders, so it is impossible for one to pick up a long-running stream in the middle. If the Opus headers could be repeated periodically, it would be possible for a receiver to be attached to an Opus stream anywhere, and start decoding when the headers appeared, but I haven't found anything in the RFCs or other docs that would allow this.

It would be possible to insert headers by ending and restarting the stream, thus breaking the stream into a number of short pieces, but I don't know if existing decoders would output the result as a continuous stream of decoded audio or not.

Is there is a way to structure a long-running Ogg/Opus stream so existing players (e.g., vlc) could play it correctly regardless of where they happen to pick it up?